# combine employee work days and leave days entry in single report

Tags: sql

I have one table in which employees daily login entry is present and when employee is on leave he enters leave date entry in other Leave table .want to create monthly report which contains each employees all days records whether he is on leave or worked on that day.
Please help how i can achieve this .

```
DECLARE @user_id int
Declare @myresultset Cursor
Set @myresultset = CURSOR for Select USER_ID from users where user_id=679
OPEN @myresultset 
Fetch NEXT from @myresultset
into @user_id
While @@Fetch_Status=0
Begin
 While @user_id is not NULL
  Begin
  
  --SELECT timesheet_id
--INTO #variable
Declare @ts TABLE (Value INT)

INSERT INTO @ts (Value)
SELECT timesheet_id 
FROM  timesheet where user_id=@user_id and MONTH(start_time_server)=month(getdate()) and year(start_time_server)=YEAR(getdate()) and user_id=679
    
  End
  declare @le_ts table (Value INT)
  Insert into @le_ts (Value) 
  select timesheet_id from leaves where start_time_server not in (select start_time_server from  timesheet where timesheet_id in (select  * from  @ts)) and user_id=@user_id

  select *,timesheet.login_by from @ts,@le_ts,timesheet where timesheet.user_id=@user_id
 Fetch Next from @myresultset
 into @user_id
 
End
close @myresultset
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu4MA.png)

Comment: You are overcomplicating the heck out of this.  You should be able to do this with a simple query.  Show some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: @Andrew , Please find image uploaded above . having sample data and final report .

Comment: As per question guidelines, pls do not post images

Comment: @Andrew , please refer given image and provide your expert advice . Thanks ,

Comment: I am not trying to be rude, but my advice is to learn how to write SQL.  If you have specific questions, ask them here, but we aren't going to just write your query for you.  Also, do not use images, much less links to images.  Not everyone can see images, people can't copy it out to work on it, etc.

Comment: Please read this: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)